# Processing (P5JS) curveVertex Not connecting 1st & 2nd Points, though vertex() Will

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm drawing a curve in P5JS using the `beginShape()` and `endShape()` functions. When adding points to my shape (a line) I'm doing so via the `curveVertex()` function. However, the final curve does not create a segment between `points[0]` and `points[1]` for some reason. If I add the points to the curve via the `vertex()` function instead, the first segment *is* drawn. Relevant code:

```js
function draw() {
  

  
  // Loop through creating line segments
  beginShape()
  noFill()
  
  // Add the first point
  stroke('black')
  strokeWeight(5)
  curveVertex(x, y)
  
  // Save points, draw last
  let points = []
  points.push({x: x, y: y})
  
  // Draw line
  for (let i = 0; i < segments; i++){
    
    // Get random y
    yRand = random(-(height * 0.125), height * 0.125);
    
    // Add point to curve
    curveVertex(x += length / segments, y += yRand);
    
    // Save point
    points.push({x: x, y: y})
    
  }
  // Draw Last Point
  curveVertex(x, y)
  endShape()
  
  // Draw the last point & segment
  stroke('#ff9900')
  strokeWeight(10)
  points.push({x: x, y: y})
  points.forEach(function(p){
    point(p.x, p.y)
  })
  
  
  // Draw the line once and stop
  noLoop();
}
```

This produces the following image:

[image: curveVertext mode]

You can see a missing segment between points[0] and points[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaFLH.png). Now, if I replace curveVertex() with vertex() in the three places in my code, I get the following image:

[image: vertex]

As you can see, the first segment *is* drawn here. If I use `endShape(CLOSE)` I get the first segment using the `curveVertex` mode—but also get a line drawn between `points[0]` and `points[-1]` (which is unwanted behavior)

**My question**: what's the difference between `vertex()` and `curveVertex()` that would omit the first segment?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/curveVertex):

> The first and last points in a series of curveVertex() lines will be used to guide the beginning and end of a the curve. A minimum of four points is required to draw a tiny curve between the second and third points. Adding a fifth point with curveVertex() will draw the curve between the second, third, and fourth points.

Essentially, the workaround seems to be to add a duplicate point for both the start and end of a curve unless one should choose to add the `CLOSE` argument to the `endShape()` function.

This produces the following image:

[image]

All that is required is to duplicate the `curveVertex(x, y)` call for the start and endpoints. So a collection of points `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` would essentially become `{1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5}` . Strange, but predictable.